# Multiple inputs for a 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> ">

            <?php
                for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++){ ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student:
                            <select name="student[<?=$x?>]">
                                <option disabled selected value> - Select Student - </option>
                                <option value="Jane">Jane</option>
                                <option value="Michelle">Michelle</option>
                                <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
                                <option value="Eddie">Eddie</option>
                                <option value="Sophie">Sophie</option>              
                            </select>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>    


                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th colspan=6>Comment</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ ){ 
                        ?>
                        <tr style="background-color:#D4F5F7">
                            <td>

                                <select name="selection[<?=$x?>][<?=$i?>]">
                                    <option disabled selected value> - Select Author - </option>
                                    <option value="Mark Twaine">Mark Twaine</option>
                                    <option value="E A Poe">Edgar Allan Poe</option>
                                    <option value="James Joyce">James Joyce</option>
                                    <option value="Oscar Wilde">Oscar Wilde</option>
                                    <option value="Tolstoy">Leo Tolstoy</option>                
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan=6>
                                   <textarea style="width: 100%;" name="comment[<?=$x?>][<?=$i?>]"> </textarea>
                            </td>
                        <?php 
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <?php 
        }   ?>

                <div class="button-section">
                    <input id="save_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
                    <input id="exit_button" type="submit" name="exit" value="Exit">
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $student = $_POST['student'];
            $selection = $_POST['selection'];
            $comment = $_POST['comment'];   

   for($y = 0; $y <= $x; $y++ ){ 
    echo $student[$y]." selected: <br/>";
    for($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++ ){
     echo $selection[$y][$j].' Comment: '. $comment[$y][$j]."<br/>";
    }
            }
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

Using the solutions, we are getting each student and every author they selected.
However, the main problem I was facing was relating the Author and Comment for each one of the Author’s by every student.
I read several examples in SO and various other websites which dealt with multi-dimensional arrays, but couldn’t find similar examples. 
During the long Easter break, I tried the following and got the desired result. But I am also getting several lines with ‘Undefined offset:’ 
Example: Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\array.php on line 72 etc. (screenshot attached)
I am not very good with arrays and hence some help with this would be very helpful.

Comment: what is you php version ? 
<? without php + <?=  it's not valid statements for newer version of php 
to get it php -v cmd , <?php phpinfo(); ?> in code

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't open a new table right after a `</tr>`.

Comment: i was updating a framework from php 5.2.0 to 7.0.2 this was from the thing which was need to be fixed to make the code work :)
but you are correct i just test 
http://joxi.ru/8An9X5eTqDqyl2

Comment: @JehadAhmadJaghoub - It's the short open tags `<?` has been disabled as default (it can be turned on in php.ini, but shouldn't be used) but the short echo `<?=` is still available and totally fine to use.

Comment: Hi Magnus, a few lines went missing when I pasted the codes. Have copied them again. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i under stand you well 
but this i think what you want  ? result 
http://joxi.net/Vm6Ry5PUxGjYjm
Code

```
<form method="post" action="/testphp">

    <?php
                     for ($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++){ ?>
                     <table>
                         <tr>
                             <th>Student:
                                 <select name="student[<?=$x?>]['Student']">
                                     <option disabled selected value> - Select Student - </option>
                                     <option value="Jane">Jane</option>
                                     <option value="Michelle">Michelle</option>
                                     <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
                                     <option value="Eddie">Eddie</option>
                                     <option value="Sophie">Sophie</option>
                                 </select>
                             </th>
                         </tr>
                         <table>
                             <tr>
                                 <th>Author</th>
                                 <th colspan=6>Comment</th>
                             </tr>
                             <?php
                             for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++ ){
                             ?>
                             <tr style="background-color:#D4F5F7">
                                 <td>
                                 <select name="student[<?=$x?>]['authorId'][<?=$i?>]">
                                 <option disabled selected value> - Select Author - </option>
                                 <option value="Mark Twaine">Mark Twaine</option>
                                 <option value="E A Poe">Edgar Allan Poe</option>
                                 <option value="James Joyce">James Joyce</option>
                                 <option value="Oscar Wilde">Oscar Wilde</option>
                                 <option value="Tolstoy">Leo Tolstoy</option>
                                 </select>
                                 </select>
                                 </td>
                                 <td colspan=6>
                                        <textarea style="width: 100%;" name="student[<?=$x?>]['comments'][<?=$i?>]"> </textarea>
                                 </td>
                             <?php
                             }
                         ?>
                                 </tr>
                         </table>
                     </table>
                     <?php
             }   ?>

                     <div class="button-section">
                         <input id="save_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
                         <input id="exit_button" type="submit" name="exit" value="Exit">
                     </div>
             </form>
```

dump($_Request);
// i make code 2 in for each for less information to fill on compile :)

```
array:2 [▼
  "student" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "'Student'" => "Michelle"
      "'authorId'" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "Mark Twaine"
        1 => "E A Poe"
      ]
      "'comments'" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "Comment From Mark to Michelle"
        1 => "Comment From Edgar to Michelle"
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "'Student'" => "Jane"
      "'authorId'" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "James Joyce"
        1 => "Oscar Wilde"
      ]
      "'comments'" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "Comment From James to Jane"
        1 => "Comment From Oscar to Jane"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "submit" => "Save"
]
```

note : `<select name="selection[<?=$student?>][<?=$i?>]">`
i didn't understand what you mean by $student you didn't identify on code mb you mean $x ?

Comment: Hi Jehad, thanks for your reply, what I want to achieve is: comment on authors from a few students. I have attached a screenshot of the form. The purpose of $student is to identify the 'author' selected by each student. I know this is not easy task for me as I have read several articles on this, and I may have missed something very important in my codes. That is where I seek help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The variable's first index is not being defined in your code. You need to declare the different variables and later write your output in the following way..

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="yourfile.php">

            <?php
                for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++){ ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student:
                            <select name="student[<?=$x?>]">
                                <option disabled selected value> - Select Student - </option>
                                <option value="Jane">Jane</option>
                                <option value="Michelle">Michelle</option>
                                <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
                                <option value="Eddie">Eddie</option>
                                <option value="Sophie">Sophie</option>              
                            </select>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>    


                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th colspan=6>Comment</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ ){ 
                        ?>
                        <tr style="background-color:#D4F5F7">
                            <td>

                                <select name="selection[<?=$x?>][<?=$i?>]">
                                    <option disabled selected value> - Select Author - </option>
                                    <option value="Mark Twaine">Mark Twaine</option>
                                    <option value="E A Poe">Edgar Allan Poe</option>
                                    <option value="James Joyce">James Joyce</option>
                                    <option value="Oscar Wilde">Oscar Wilde</option>
                                    <option value="Tolstoy">Leo Tolstoy</option>                
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan=6>
                                   <textarea style="width: 100%;" name="comment[<?=$x?>][<?=$i?>]"> </textarea>
                            </td>
                        <?php 
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <?php 
        }   ?>

                <div class="button-section">
                    <input id="save_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
                    <input id="exit_button" type="submit" name="exit" value="Exit">
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $student = $_POST['student'];
            $selection = $_POST['selection'];
            for( $i=0 ; $i<3 ; $i++) {
               echo $student[$i] . ' read ' . '<br>' ;
               for( $j=0 ; $j<3 ; $j++) {
                  echo $j+1 .' . ' . $selection[$i][$j]." and commented ".$comment[$i][$j].'<br>';
               }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Nawaz,
Thanks for your reply. Using your method, we are getting each student and every author they selected.
However, the main problem I was facing was relating the Author and Comment for each one of the Author’s by every student.
I have edited the question for some advise on the Undefined offset errors that I am getting now.

Comment: your question was different previously (before your edit) and it doesn't include comments problem. I would prefer you to ask a new question instead of editing the same if you got stuck in the next step of your code.

Comment: Hi Nawaz, being new to this site, I wasn't able to add the edited code, hence I had to overwrite the original one. However, the comment for every Author selected was the most important part of this question. This is a 'one to many' relationship, rather than 'one to one', which is the interesting part. If you see my reply to Jehad (on 27-Mar) you will find that I mentioned: 'what I want to achieve is: comment on authors from a few students'. Anyway, thanks for all your effort.

Comment: @guptagee it's ok.  you are welcome. Do accept and upvote the answers if you seem that it had helped you .

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> ">

            <?php
                for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++){ ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student:
                            <select name="student[<?=$x?>]">
                                <option disabled selected value> - Select Student - </option>
                                <option value="Jane">Jane</option>
                                <option value="Michelle">Michelle</option>
                                <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
                                <option value="Eddie">Eddie</option>
                                <option value="Sophie">Sophie</option>              
                            </select>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>    


                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th colspan=6>Comment</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ ){ 
                        ?>
                        <tr style="background-color:#D4F5F7">
                            <td>

                                <select name="selection[<?=$x?>][<?=$i?>]">
                                    <option disabled selected value> - Select Author - </option>
                                    <option value="Mark Twaine">Mark Twaine</option>
                                    <option value="E A Poe">Edgar Allan Poe</option>
                                    <option value="James Joyce">James Joyce</option>
                                    <option value="Oscar Wilde">Oscar Wilde</option>
                                    <option value="Tolstoy">Leo Tolstoy</option>                
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan=6>
                                   <textarea style="width: 100%;" name="comment[<?=$x?>][<?=$i?>]"> </textarea>
                            </td>
                        <?php 
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <?php 
        }   ?>

                <div class="button-section">
                    <input id="save_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
                    <input id="exit_button" type="submit" name="exit" value="Exit">
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $student = (isset($_POST['student']) ? $_POST['student'] : '');
            $selection = (isset($_POST['selection']) ? $_POST['selection'] : ''); 
            $comment = (isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : '');   

   for($y = 0; $y <= $x; $y++ ){
    if(!empty($student[$y])){
     echo $student[$y]." selected: <br/>";
     for($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++ ){
      if(!empty($selection[$y][$j])){
       echo $selection[$y][$j].' Comment: '. $comment[$y][$j]."<br/>";
      }
     }
    }
            }
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

After a couple of hours of troubleshooting I got it working...!! :D